# php and utf-8 and &nbsp;

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities

When I run this piece of code (it is isolated to the core issue from my complicated solution)

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode('A&nbsp;A'), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' ));
```

result is

```
string(0) ""
```

any ideas why/how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: what result where you expecting?

Comment: couple ot tests show it depends what php version you are using to run it some return A A

Comment: demo here: http://3v4l.org/1Eb9V